# Open FBSession in Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook, swift

How can i open an new FBSession in Swift? I have a Facebook login currently that is working perfect, and now i want to get the friends in a new controller.

I currently have this:

```
var friendsRequest : FBRequest = FBRequest.requestForMyFriends()
    friendsRequest.startWithCompletionHandler{(connection:FBRequestConnection!, result:AnyObject!, error:NSError!) -> Void in
        var resultdict = result as NSDictionary
        println("dict: \(resultdict)")
        var data : NSArray = resultdict.objectForKey("data") as NSArray

        for i in 0...data.count {
            let valueDict : NSDictionary = data[i] as NSDictionary
            let id = valueDict.objectForKey("id") as String
            println("id \(id)")
        }

        var friends = resultdict.objectForKey("data") as NSArray
        println("\(friends.count) friends")
    }
```

And this is giving me this error:

FBSDKLog: Error for request to endpoint 'me/friends': An open FBSession must be specified for calls to this endpoint.

How can i achieve this? I can't seem to find this..

Answer (score 0):

```
var friendsRequest : FBRequest = FBRequest.requestForMyFriends()

friendsRequest.startWithCompletionHandler{(connection:FBRequestConnection!,     result:AnyObject!, error:NSError!) -> Void in

var resultdict = result as NSDictionary

println("Result Dict: \(resultdict)")

var data : NSArray = resultdict.objectForKey("data") as NSArray

    for i in 0...data.count {
        let valueDict : NSDictionary = data[i] as NSDictionary
        let id = valueDict.objectForKey("id") as String
        println("the id value is \(id)")


    }

    var friends = resultdict.objectForKey("data") as NSArray
        println("Found \(friends.count) friends")

    }
```